# Python Tweepy 4.4 streamlistener attribute not found?

Tags: python, stream, tweepy

I'm trying to listen for a certain character in a tweet from a specific twitter account.

I get a compile time error.

Here's the relevant pieces of the code:

```py
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):
    
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
  
def main():
    api = twitter_authentication() #this function does the necessary twitter auth

    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(track=["test"], follow=["123456"])
```

When I run this in pycharm, I get the following error:

```
line 68, in <module>
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):
AttributeError: module 'tweepy.streaming' has no attribute 'StreamListener'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy v4.0.0 was released recently and it merged StreamListener into Stream.

You should update your code to subclass Stream instead or you could also change the version to v3.10.0 .

I suppose you could do what you want to do like that:

```
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:  # end of monthly limit rate (500k)
            return False


stream = MyStreamListener('consumer_key',
                      'consumer_secret',
                      'access_token',
                      'access_token_secret')

stream.filter(track=["test"], follow=["123456"])
```